# CRC-16 algorithm (with the generator polynom 0x8005)?

Tags: vb.net, crc16

I've been working on a VB.NET version of reading then MPEG Frame Header of an MP3 file. One of the ways to test if you found the correct frame header is to check the the CRC value with next two bytes that come after the frame header. I don't understand CRC and I have no clue what polynom 0x8005 means. Can someone please guide me in the right direction. I don't understand anything when it comes to this. Thanks.

Comment: ` I don't understand anything when it comes to this`  doesnt that just mean you have research to do?  Sorry, but this is not a tutorial site.  That said there is at least one NuGet package for doing all sorts of checksums and hashes.  I know that have several CRC methods, not sure if they have CRC16 because.

Comment: Yeah I really didn't want to ask and I have done research it's just when I read about CRC's they seems to not be with polynom 0x8005. I'm still trying to understand CRC's in general.

Comment: My question: ***what do you want to do with the frameheader?***

Comment: Read [Ross Williams' excellent tutorial on CRCs](http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt). Also you will need more information on the CRC than just the polynomial. Is it reflected or not? What is the initial CRC and what post-processing is done? Is the CRC stored in the stream in little or big-endian order? [Here is a list of 16-bit CRCs seen in the wild](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm).

Comment: Looking at some [mp3 source code](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/_modules/eyed3/mp3/headers.html), it appears to the the [ARC CRC](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm#crc.cat.arc), which is reflected, initial value 0, final xor 0. Also it is stored in the stream in big-endian order.

Answer (score 0):

CRC requires a [generator polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) which can be different for various CRC implementations. In case of mp3 (and mpeg-1 audio in general) it's 0x8005, specifically the CRC is the [CRC-16/CMS](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/16.htm#crc.cat.crc-16-cms) variant (not CRC-16/ARC like mentioned in a comment). So for implementation you can refer either to the parameters of the variant, or use a preexisting implementation since it's a common variant..